# MyBatis Get Last Insert Id

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, insert, mybatis

I have a Java POJO:

```
public class Widget {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    // ...
}
```

I am trying to use MyBatis to insert a new `Widget` into the `widget` table of my Postgres database, and for this insert method to inject the passed-in POJO with the auto-generated id of the newly-inserted `widget` table record:

```
// Notice the widget's id is left null.
Widget w = new Widget("name-of-widget");

WidgetMapperImpl widgetMapper = new WidgetMapperImpl();
widgetMapper.insertWidget(w);

// At runtime this prints null (the id is not being set).
System.out.println(w.getId());
```

And `WidgetMapper.java`:

```
public interface WidgetMapper {
    public void insertWidget(@Param("widget") Widget widget);
}
```

Here is the `WidgetMapper.xml`:

```
<mapper namespace="com.myapp.WidgetMapper">
    <cache flushInterval="360000" />

    <resultMap id="WidgetMapperResult" type="com.myapp.Widget">
        <result property="id" column="widget_id"/>
        <result property="name" column="widget_name" />
    </resultMap>

    <insert id="insertWidget" parameterType="com.myapp.Widget" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id">
        INSERT INTO
            myapp.widgets
            (
                widget_name
            )
            VALUES
            (
                #{widget.name}
            );

            <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="int" order="AFTER">
                SELECT CURRVAL('widget_id_seq') AS widget_id
            </selectKey>
    </insert>
</mapper>
```

Again, this code compiles and builds fine. At runtime, after I call `widgetMapper.insertWidget(Widget)`, and then try to access that's `Widget`'s id, it is null, so the ID-injection is not working. Can anyone spot why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, you cannot use `useGeneratedKeys="true"` and `selectKey` at the same time.

So a solution can be: either the implementation of the `getGeneratedKeys` method of the JDBC driver for Postgres can deal with what you need (I don't know how JDBC and postgres sequences works together), so you use only `useGeneratedKeys="true"`. Or you have to use `selectKey`, then you have to turn of the `useGeneratedKeys` attribute.